# Pandas dataframe creating new columns with data from other dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
pd_one
          name          Rep
0     Bob-Name           29
1    Bill-Name           23     
2     Sam-Name           46
3    Jeff-Name           17
4     Red-Name           20

pd_two
          name      sumT        total
0     Bob-0021          10      = (pd_one.bob-Name.value)-1/sumT*100
1    Bill-0220          20      = (pd_one.Bill-Name.value)-1/sumT*100
2     Sam-0020          23      = (pd_one.Sam-Name.value)-1/sumT*100
3    Jeff-0125          25      = (pd_one.Jeff-Name.value)-1/sumT*100
4     Red-1234          99      = (pd_one.Red-Name.value)-1/sumT*100
```

I want to create the totals column in pd_two using a value from pd_one as part of the sum. The value should be taken from pd_one where the column name is the same as pd_two.

Here is as far as I was able to get:

```
self.pd_one = pd.DataFrame(pd_one_data)
self.pd_two = pd.DataFrame(pd_two_data)
self.pd_one.sort_values(by=['name'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
self.pd_two.sort_values(by=['name'], ascending = True, inplace = True)

name_ftr = self.pd_two.name[:].str.partition('-')[0]+'-Name'
```

From here I just need to find the series in pd_one with name_ftr and take the value of the Rep cell
and use it to do the calculations and to make and fill the new column in pd_two.

I am struggling to work out the syntax for doing this, I've been trying to use .loc but I can't seem to get the data from pd_one['Rep'] without running into errors.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (or [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)) your dataframes?

Comment: I don't wish to merge the two dataframes, I just need the rep value from one dataframe based on name then with the value, do the maths and create a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
pd_one = pd.DataFrame(
[['Bob-Name', 29],
['Bill-Name',23],
['Sam-Name',46],
['Jeff-Name',17],
['Red-Name',20]], columns = ['name', 'Rep'])

pd_two = pd.DataFrame([['Bob-0021', 10],
['Bill-0220', 20],
['Sam-0020', 23],
['Jeff-0125', 25],
['Red-1234', 99]], columns = ['name', 'sumT'])

pd_one['name_unique'] = pd_one['name'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-')[0])
pd_two['name_unique'] = pd_two['name'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-')[0])

merged_df = pd.merge(pd_one, pd_two, on = 'name_unique')
merged_df['total'] = (merged_df['Rep'] - 1) / merged_df['sumT'] * 100

merged_df
```

The output is

```
    name_x  Rep name_unique name_y  sumT    total
0   Bob-Name    29  Bob Bob-0021    10  280.000000
1   Bill-Name   23  Bill    Bill-0220   20  110.000000
2   Sam-Name    46  Sam Sam-0020    23  195.652174
3   Jeff-Name   17  Jeff    Jeff-0125   25  64.000000
4   Red-Name    20  Red Red-1234    99  19.191919
```

Here, name_x is name from pd_one, and name_y is name from pd_two.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't wish to merge the dataframes, I just need the value in the first dataframe so I can do the math and make the new column in the second dataframe

Comment: In this case, you just use merged_df['total'].

Comment: That does work, but I didn't explain properly. In the case where there is two entries of one name  in pd_two e.g Jeff-0125, Jeff-0928 both totals for Jeff will need to be calculated from the jeff rep in pd_one, hope that makes sense thanks.

Comment: That is called "aggregation" ;-)